# gnuplot multiplot equal height of each plot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, height, equals

i want to make a gnuplot multiplot with three plots above each other. it worked so far, when i dont add a x-axis label and set every tmargin and bmargin equal. but when i add a x-axis label und xtics under the lowest plot, this plot shrinks in its height - like the image shows. do you have an idea how to make equal sized plots with a x-axis label under the lowest plot? [image]

this is my code:

```
reset

set lmargin 9
set rmargin 3
unset key

set xrange [-1:41]

set boxwidth 0.4
set style fill solid noborder

set multiplot layout 3,1

set xtics format ""
set xtics 5
unset xlabel
set ytics 100
set logscale y
set format y "10^{%L}"

set key ins vert right top
set tmargin 0.8
set bmargin 0.5
set yrange [1:100000000]
#set ylabel "Photonen / s  [Mio.]" offset 0,0,0 font ""
plot "300sLinienMit0.txt" u (($1)):($2/300) w boxes lc rgb "#6699ff" title "185,72 keV"

set xtics format ""
unset xlabel

set ytics 10
set tmargin 0.5
set bmargin 0.5
set yrange [1:1000]
set ylabel "Photonen [s^{-1}]" offset -2,0,0 font ""
plot "300sLinienMit0.txt" u ($1):($3/300) w boxes lc rgb "#ff6600" title "351,03 keV"
unset ylabel

set xtics format ""
unset xlabel

set tmargin 0.5
set yrange [1:1000]
set format x "%g"

set xtics 5 offset 0,0,0
set bmargin 3.5
set xlabel "Blei-Abschirmung [mm]" offset 0,0,0 font "" 
#set ylabel "Photonen / s  [Tsd.]" offset 0,0,0 font ""
plot "300sLinienMit0.txt" u ($1):($4/300) w boxes lc -1 title "831,98 keV"

unset multiplot
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the positions and sizes of your (sub-)plots yourself within the multiplot environment.
Important is to `set bmargin 0`. The margin of the bottom plot you set via `set origin 0, myBottomMargin`. And then set the origins and sizes of the other plots accordingly. I hope the following code is self-explaining.

**Code:**

```
### multiplot with equal plot heights
reset session

myBottomMargin = 0.15
myPlotHeight = (1. - myBottomMargin)/3

set multiplot

    set xlabel "This is the xlabel for all plots"
    set ytics 0.5
    set grid xtics, ytics
    set origin 0, myBottomMargin
    set size 1, myPlotHeight
    set bmargin 0
    set label 1 at graph 1.0, graph 1.0 "185.72 keV" right offset -1,-1
    plot sin(x) w l lc 1 notitle
    
    unset xlabel
    set format x ""
    set origin 0, myBottomMargin+myPlotHeight
    set label 1 at graph 1.0, graph 1.0 "351.03 keV" right offset -1,-1
    plot sin(2*x) w l lc 2 notitle
    
    set origin 0, myBottomMargin+2*myPlotHeight
    set label 1 at graph 1.0, graph 1.0 "831.98 keV" right offset -1,-1
    plot sin(3*x) w l lc 3 notitle

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: wow! perfect! thank you very much :) the only thing now is, that i dont want a symbol in the key, just a number. any idea?

Comment: Thanks for your addition. In this way the key symbol is not visible but the number e.g. "185,72" is still at the same position as before. It would be prettier when its right aligned, like the symbol in my picture above. Does anyone have an idea how to delete the symbol in the key so the title of the plot gets inside top right aligned?

Comment: i found on page 62 of the gnuplot 5.2 handbook (Version 5.2 organized by: Ethan A Merritt and many others) a plot, in which the key just has a text and no symbol, but there was no script shown - i still dont know how to do it, but its possible!

Comment: if you just want to have one number at the top right corner of each plot you could use `set label`. Check `help label`. Always use `label 1` to overwrite the previous label. I will modify the example.

Comment: @pablobanano does this answer your question? Any response appreciated.